# canMakePayment returns null on FireFox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe elements react library for a page that I process payments on. When I load my `invoice` on FireFox the `paymentRequest.canMakePayment()` method returns `null`. However, on Edge, Chrome, and Safari it renders & works as intended.

Firefox information:

Build: `latest`
Platform: `Windows 10`
Addons: `react developer tools, ad block plus`

Note: Tested with adblock off.

Code for the `PaymentRequestButtonElement` injection.

```
class _StripeButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const paymentRequest = props
            .stripe
            .paymentRequest({
                country: 'US',
                currency: 'usd',
                total: {
                    label: " Subscription",
                    amount: 100
                },
                requestPayerName: true,
                requestPayerEmail: true
            });

        paymentRequest.on('token', ({
            complete,
            token,
            ...data
        }) => {
            complete('success');
        });

        paymentRequest
            .canMakePayment()
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("DONE: ", result);
                this.setState({
                    canMakePayment: !!result
                });
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        this.state = {
            canMakePayment: false,
            paymentRequest
        };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.canMakePayment) {
            return (<PaymentRequestButtonElement
                paymentRequest={this.state.paymentRequest}
                className="PaymentRequestButton"
                style={{
                paymentRequestButton: {
                    theme: 'dark',
                    height: '64px'
                }
            }}/>);
        }

        return <Loading/>;
    }
}

const StripeButton = injectStripe(_StripeButton);
```

Component that renders the button:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <StripeProvider stripe={this.state.stripe}>
                <Elements>
                    <StripeButton/>
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
        );
    }
```

If I manually toggle `this.state.canMakePayment` to true in the developer tools I get the error `Error: The paymentRequestButton Element is not available in the current environment.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (15th Feb 2019), Firefox's Payment Request API is only available for their nightly builds. Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaymentRequest/PaymentRequest) at the bottom of the page.